# Apache Kafka Consumer sometimes does not write to console in Windows 7: "Unable to write to standard out, closing consumer."

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Apache Kafka Consumer returns "Unable to write to standard out, closing consumer." in Windows 7 in some cases. It works fine for the same messages in Linux and Windows 8 and for other shorter messages in Windows 7. I wonder whether anyone has already faced this problem? Can it depend on the size of messages and how this issue can be solved?

Answer (score -1):

I face the same problem on Windows 7 too. It seem that decrease the size of kafka messages that you produce in the topic resolve the issue.